# Ruby - Is there a recursive solution to find the divisors of a number?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I am doing a ruby problem that wants a method to find all divisors of a number except itself with the output being a sorted array. If the number is prime, list that it is prime.

I am currently trying to teach myself recursion. Simple recursive problems like finding the factorial of a number is pretty basic to understand but I wanted to know if this particular problem could be done recursively. It seems it fits the criteria of one that could but I could not figure it out.

Example n = 15, divisors besides itself are [3,5].

My code that solved the problem.

```
require 'prime'

def divisors(n)
  return "#{n} is prime" if Prime.prime?(n) 
  x = n/2
  arr = []
  until x == 1
    arr << x if n % x == 0
    x -= 1
  end 
  arr.sort
end
```

Any help doing this recursively would be great or just letting me know it's not a problem that can be done this way would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

```
def divisors(n, x=nil)
  return "#{n} is prime" if Prime.prime?(n) 
  x ||= n/2
  arr = []
  return arr if x == 1
  if n % x == 0
    arr << x
  end
  (arr.concat divisors(n, x - 1)).sort
end
```

The function is refactored to handle three things:

- the initial call (`x ||= /2`)
- base cases (early returns)
- iteration logic done through recursion.

An important thing is that the variable which changes during the iteration (`x`) is placed as a parameter for the method (with a default value, so it can essentially be used as a private parameter)

By the way, I personally found learning Elixir very helpful in understanding recursion. With pattern matching and multiple functional clauses, the initial call, base case, and iteration can be split into their own methods.

Comment: i think you have missed to specify variable `n` in the list which you specified. **the initial call `(x ||= n/2)`** .

Comment: N is passed to the function as an argument